# Method signature has invalid calling convention from a csproj file (0x80131239)

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code

Until today one of our applications was running correctly in Visual Studio code (the majority of devs use Visual Studio 2019).  However, after a pull from git this morning we are getting the following error when building the project.

```
dotnet build

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5): error : Process terminated. System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80131239): Method signature has invalid calling convention. (0x80131239) [<MyDiirectory>\<MyProject>.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.InternalSyntax.LanguageParser.ParseLocalDeclarationStatement(SyntaxToken awaitKeywordOpt) [<MyDiirectory>\<MyProject>.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.InternalSyntax.LanguageParser.ParsePossibleDeclarationOrBadAwai  tStatement(ResetPoint& resetPointBeforeStatement) [<MyDiirectory>\<MyProject>.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.InternalSyntax.LanguageParser.ParsePossibleDeclarationOrBadAwaitStatement() [<MyDiirectory>\<MyProject>.csproj]
```

The actual csproj file is nothing out of the ordinary:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.2.0\ref\netcoreapp2.2\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
 </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Report\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="SolrNet.Core" Version="1.0.19" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I've tried the following:

- Complete clean and rebuild
- Clear the proj file and recreate
- Restart of VS code
- Checked for legacy DLL references

Has anyone come across this problem, specifically in Visual Studio code?  As I say it works fine on Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Could you post your actual code?  Without seeing the calling convention in question this is hard to guess at.

Comment: Try creating a new local repo folder .. i had a similar issue where my git repo metadata got corrupted and someone another version of the file still persisted in my folder.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer.  This is happening at build time, not run-time.  I've updated the question.